# Nifi v1.13.0 throwing an error not a supported type DECIMAL error while parsing CSV file using SplitRecord & UpdateRecord

Tags: apache-nifi, avro

Getting above error trying to process a csv file with a decimal field. This error is specific to Nifi version 1.13.0. No error is thrown using v1.10.0.

Below is a sample scenario

**samplefile.csv**

| "uid" | "decNum" | "dob" | "timeMillis" | "timeMicros" | "timeStampMillis" | "timeStampMicros" | "localTimeStampMicros" | "localTimeStampMillis" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "67799edc-11b8-11ec-82a8-0242ac130003" | "130.50" | "12345" | "14540334" | "14540334343" | "1634845704629" | "1634845704629556" | "1634845704629556" | "1634845704629" |
| "d7130d85-cb94-49b1-a722-d3c842f77d01" | "0.11" | "20045" | "16348504" | "16348508141" | "1580477014345" | "1580477014345556" | "1580477014345556" | "1580477014345" |

For illustration, I used a `SplitRecord` processor, but same is received for `UpdateRecord` processor.

Sample flow looks like: ListSFTP -> FetchSFTP -> SplitRecord -> Funnel(End)

**SplitRecord**

[image: SplitRecord configuration]

RecordReader is a custom controller service that works more like a csvreader with additives-CdrReader_TEST_PFX

**CdrReader_TEST_PFX**

[image: CdrReader_TEST_PFX configuration]

**SchemaText**

```json
{“type”:”record”,”name”:”pxf”,”namespace”:”pxf”,”fields”:[{“name”:”uid”,”type”:{“type”:”string”,”logicalType”:”uuid”}},{“name”:”decNum”,”type”:{“type”:”bytes”,”logicalType”:”decimal”,”precision”:4,”scale”:2}},{“name”:”dob”,”type”:{“type”:”int”,”logicalType”:”date”}},{“name”:”timeMillis”,”type”:{“type”:”int”,”logicalType”:”time-millis”}},{“name”:”timeMicros”,”type”:{“type”:”long”,”logicalType”:”time-micros”}},{“name”:”timeStampMillis”,”type”:{“type”:”long”,”logicalType”:”timestamp-millis”,”doc”:”uuid type”}},{“name”:”timeStampMicros”,”type”:{“type”:”long”,”logicalType”:”timestamp-micros”,”doc”:”uuid type”}},{“name”:”localTimeStampMicros”,”type”:{“type”:”long”,”logicalType”:”local-timestamp-micros”,”doc”:”localTimeStamp type”}},{“name”:”localTimeStampMillis”,”type”:{“type”:”long”,”logicalType”:”local-timestamp-millis”,”doc”:”localTimeStamp type”}}],”doc:”:”PXF Avro Record”}
```

**RecordWriter**

[image: Record writer configuration]

Specific error received is as below:

[image]

Deployed the pipeline on a different cluster running `v1.10.0` and this ran successfully. Not sure what happened with `v1.13.0`.